# Tastypie following a reverse relationship - not working to use related_name

Tags: django, tastypie

I have two models.

Parent

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    ... code
```

Child

```
class Child(models.Model):
    ... code
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name="parents")
```

And an API

```
class ParentResource(ModelResource):
    children = fields.ToManyField("project.module.api.ChildResource", 'children', related_name='parents', null=True, blank=True, full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Parent.objects.all()
```

and

```
class ChildResource(ModelResource):
    parent = fields.ForeignKey("project.module.api.ParentResource", 'parent')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Child.objects.all()
```

When I try to visit the parent resource, the array for `children` is empty. Any help clarifying would be welcome.

I've looked at previous answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838828/reverse-lookup-by-foreignkey-in-tastypie) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999188/django-tastypie-one-to-many-relationship) and the docs [here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#tastypie.fields.RelatedField.related_name) but I'm still not able to see what is going on.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code:

```
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name="parents")
```

`related_name` sets the attribute name on the `Parent` model (also does the same on tastypie resources), with the default being `child_set` and you're now setting it to `parents`. That means a `Parent` model `p` would have a queryset of `Child` objects at the attribute named `parents`, which is obviously not right.

Additionally, the related_name on `ChildResource` for the parent relationship doesn't match the attribute on the related model.

Below are corrected versions of each that should just work:

### Models

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    ... code

class Child(models.Model):
    ... code
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name="children")
```

### Resources

```
class ParentResource(ModelResource):
    children = fields.ToManyField("project.module.api.ChildResource", 'children', related_name='parent', null=True, blank=True, full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Parent.objects.all()

class ChildResource(ModelResource):
    parent = fields.ForeignKey("project.module.api.ParentResource", 'parent')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Child.objects.all()
```

Comment: Thanks @lukeman. That makes sense for Django Models, but I'm not sure that's right for Django-Tastypie. I think I've avoided it long enough and I might need to switch to backbone-relational instead of "sort of" doing it. KNWIM?

Comment: To my eyes your Tastypie resources look mostly fine. The related name on `ParentResource` is off though. I'll update my answer with new models/resources for each that should work fine.

Comment: Also, backbone-relational is an unrelated choice. It's a neat way of getting your backbone code more aware of relationships (and it involves some basic caching IIRC), but if your resources aren't dehydrating properly that's neither here nor there.